# Transpile these ES6 arrow functions!

Tags: code-golf

The ECMAScript 6 standard added many new features to the JavaScript language, including a new [arrow function notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Your task is to write a basic ES6-to-ES5 transpiler. Given only an ES6 arrow function as input, output its ES5-compatible counterpart.

It's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)! May the shortest program in bytes win!

---

### The Basics

An arrow function looks like this:

```
(a, b, c) => { return a + b - c }
```

And its equivalent ES5 function expression looks like this:

```
function(a, b, c) { return a + b - c }
```

In general, you can copy the body of the function (everything between the curly braces) verbatim.

---

### Implicit Return Statement

Instead of a body with curly braces, a single expression can be used; the result of this expression is then returned.

```
(a, b, c) => a + b - c

function(a, b, c) { return a + b - c }
```

Another example:

```
(a, b, c) => (a + 1, b - 2 * c / 3)

function(a, b, c) { return (a + 1, b - 2 * c / 3) }
```

Again, you may simply copy the expression verbatim - BUT take care that you do not output a line break between it and the `return` keyword to avoid automatic semicolon insertion!

---

### One Argument

Parentheses are optional if one argument is provided.

```
foo => { return foo + 'bar' }

function(foo) { return foo + 'bar' }
```

---

### Whitespace

Finally, you must be able to account for any number of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline) before or after parentheses, variables, commas, curly braces, and the arrow*.

```
 ( o   ,  O
     , _    )=>{

    return                                     "Please don't write code like this."
}
```

Whether or not you choose to preserve whitespace in the output is up to you. Keep 'em, remove 'em, or add your own - just make sure it's valid code!

<sub>*It's technically illegal for an arrow to come immediately after a line break, but I doubt this fact would help you. :)</sub>

---

### A quick way to validate your output:

Enter `var foo = <your output>; foo()` into your browser console. If it doesn't complain, you're probably on the right track.

---

### More rules for the wizards:

- Input is a syntactically valid ES6 arrow function.
- Assume the body of the function is ES5-compatible (and doesn't reference `this`, `super`, `arguments`, etc). This also means that the function will never contain another arrow function (but you may not assume that "=>" will never occur within the body).
- Variable names will only consist of basic Latin letters, `$` and `_`.
- You need not transpile ES6 features that aren't listed above (default parameters, rest operator, destructuring, etc).
- The space after a `return` statement is optional if followed by `(`, `[`, or `{`.
- It isn't strictly necessary to match my test cases exactly - you can modify the code as much as you need if it'll help lower your byte count. Really, as long as you produce a syntactically valid, functionally equivalent ES5 function expression, you're golden!

Comment: May we assume the input is a syntactically valid arrow function and nothing else?

Comment: An edge case would be `a =>\na`, where `function(a){ return\na }` would actually return `undefined` no matter what the value of `a` is. Do we need to handle this?

Comment: @ETHproductions Don't you just love those automagic semicolons!

Comment: Will we get nested ES6 functions?

Comment: Can we assume that the input will only contain a single `=>`?

Comment: @Riker It is done.

Comment: @ETHproductions: Yes, and yes.

Comment: @KritixiLithos: No.

Comment: @mathjunkie: No.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>123</s> <s>110</s> <s>100</s> 97 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```
s=>s.replace(/\(?(.*?)\)?\s*=>\s*([^]*)/,(_,a,b)=>`function(${a})${b[0]=='{'?b:`{return ${b}}`}`)
```

Assumes the input is a syntactically valid arrow function and nothing else. Correctly handles the case `a =>\na`, though not handling is not any shorter as far as I can tell.

Output when the code is run through itself:

```
function(s){return s.replace(/\(?(.*?)\)?\s*=>\s*([^]*)/,(_,a,b)=>`function(${a})${b[0]=='{'?b:`{return ${b}}`}`)}
```

---

I can save 9 bytes with a possibly invalid format:

```
s=>s.replace(/\(?(.*?)\)?\s*=>\s*({?)([^]*?)}?$/,(_,a,z,b)=>Function(a,z?b:'return '+b))
```

Output for itself:

```
function anonymous(s) {
return s.replace(/\(?([^=)]*)\)?\s*=>\s*({?)([^]*?)}?$/,(_,a,z,b)=>Function(a,z?b:'return '+b))
}
```

(Specifically, the `function anonymous` is what I'm worried about.)

Comment: Shame that your function itself contains a further arrow function so that when run through itself it's not actually fully transpiled.

Comment: I think `\(?(.*?)\)?\s*=>` might save you 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, <s>86</s> <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```
^([^(]*?)=
($1)=
s(`\s*$

>\s*(.*[^}])$
>{return $1}
)`(.*?)=>(.*)
function$1$2
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#jYvBCsIwGIPv/1OEUbAtMqh36yPM@1ydbBWLo4W2w4Ps2Wv1CcwhXyBJMbw3fJAncSTOVPXEx0uSjEhX8Fb2ZhsEI/2ONq/Rg6mNxFiLetEVgu6rn7ILnil2KAUcAcAe6Aj4pesXdY0/RM15sbdkMQe/y3hFly2mMFss7mmRHy61DX0A)

*Saved a byte thanks to Neil*

*Saved 6 bytes with help from ETHproductions*

**Edit:** Fixed for possibility of newlines in function body.

75 byte solution assuming the input won't contain `§`: [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@29rx3VoOVecRnScRqyWJpCpoWIIoooTDi2PKdYCilfHFMfqaWkClVUXpZaUFuUpqBjWAuU19EDqQSRXWmlecklmfp6KoYrR//9p@fkKtnYg0k5BPSmxSJ0LAA)

Comment: You can use a pilcrow instead of `\n` to save a byte.

Comment: This seems to remove line breaks within the function body, which may alter the functionality.

Comment: I think `\s` includes `¶`, so line three can be `\s*$` to save 4 bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions It seems `\s` only matches `¶` when the `s` configuration option is added. Nevertheless, it saved me some bytes

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 112 bytes

```php
preg_match("#\(??(.*)\)?=>(\{?)(.*$)#U",$argn,$m);echo"function($m[1])",trim($b=$m[3])[0]=="{"?$b:"{return $b}";
```

takes input from STDIN; run with `-R`